# Request returns not actual value

Tags: python-requests, python-3.7

I have written the following code and it works fine. I really enjoyed because I am quite new in python requests or even python3 but at the following day I noticed that the price variable is not updated. And it does not update any time I run the code for a week (709.49 if does it matter). I think it is not a secret so I pasted the whole code below with link to the website.

So I want to ask whether I wrote something in wrong way or the web page is not that simple to make a request. Could you tell me what happened?
Here is the original code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pattern = '\d+\.?\d*'

site_doc = requests.get('https://bitbay.net/pl/kurs-walut/kurs-ethereum-pln').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(site_doc, 'html.parser')

price = str(soup.select('title'))
price = re.findall(pattern, price) 
print(price)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is that the content you are trying to get is JavaScript rendered. For this, I'd recommend using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) in order to get JavaScript rendered content.

Comment: Thanks @benbaessler , with selenium I worked it out.
But is it even impossible or really difficult to do it with requests? I am just curious.